# There was no endpoint listening at...that could accept the message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf-endpoint

I'm a beginner in creating an installer in visual studio. And when I tried creating I encountered an error "There was no endpoint listening at  http://localhost:8733/eSARService/UserService/ that could accept the message.
So the situation is I have a 5 pc that is connected to one server (LAN). Offline use only.

Here's my code for app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="eSample.Properties.Settings.Sampledb" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=Sampledb;User ID=sa;Password=password"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" />                
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>            
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/eSARService/UserService/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService"
                contract="UserServiceRef.IUserService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" />
            </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

here's my service's app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SampledbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SampleModel.csdl|res://*/SampleModel.ssdl|res://*/SampleModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local)\SQL2008;initial catalog=Sampledb;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=password;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="dcBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000"
            maxArrayLength="20000000" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="eSARService.UserService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="dcBinding"
          contract="eSARService.IUserService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/eSARService/UserService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>          
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: And is there something listening at http://localhost:8733 ?

Comment: your eSARService/UserService is probably not running

Comment: is the service even exposing metadata?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen  when i ran it through visual studio, it was working ok but when i ran it after installing the setup to the pc...i see that error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx